# Adding Vertical Scrollbar in Paragraph inside Div

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph inside the Div .Now the contents of the paragraph are getting increased as i have planned to add some images but my div has a fixed height of `600px;` and so my paragraph so if veritical scrollbars gets added for my paragraph then it would solve my issue..

Here is the HTML for my layout..

```
 <div id="bodydesc" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:960px; height: 600px;">

            <p id="desc" style="float:left;color: #666666; width:700px; font-family: Candara,Trebuchet MS,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; border-right: thin dotted #666666; line-height: 18px;">

              //Here is my large content with images...

            </p>

 </div>
```

So my question is how can i get vertical scrollbar in paragraph inside the div in HTML ...
Please help me ..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short and quick answer, add a scrollbar to the `#bodydesc` by adding `overflow-y` to the style attribute:

```
<div id="bodydesc" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:960px; height: 600px; overflow-y: scroll;">

    <p id="desc" style="float:left;color: #666666; width:700px; font-family: Candara,Trebuchet MS,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; border-right: thin dotted #666666; line-height: 18px;">

      //Here is my large content with images...

    </p>

</div>
```

The front end developer that is in me insists that I tell you to move all those style declarations in an [external css file](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.3).

Comment: No need to worry about performance for such a small thing. You won't see any performance problem. A simple scrollbar is something a browser does really easily

Comment: If i am not declaring the styles in an external css what can be the possible problems..I wanted to know as per your suggestion.I am a student leaning HTML and CSS..Thanks

Comment: It's not a problem per se, it's just good practice to do so. You gain in maintainability of the code. Imagine you want all p tags to be green, in your external css you just say p {color: green}. After a month, the art director tells you he wants the paragraphs to be red. If you have inline styles in your html you'll have to change every single p tag on the site, while if you use an external css you just change it once and you're good to go. It also makes the HTML easier to read and to find stuff in it.

Answer (score 5):

add `overflow-y: scroll;` to your paragraph

Comment: shouldn't it be `overflow-y` ?

Answer (score 1):

Fix the paragraph height with the appropriate `height:...px` and add `overflow-y: auto;`

Comment: it's actually overflow-y: auto, but props for noticing he didn't fix the height

Answer (score 1):

add this to your element:

```
overflow-y:auto;
```